# Implementing PCA in C

Tags: c, matlab, pca

I am trying to optimize code. I need PCA implementation in C whose results are comparable to PCA in Matlab. I have implemented PCA from gsl library using the link [pca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625328/implementation-of-pca-principal-component-analysis-in-c-c). Below is code :

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_statistics.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_eigen.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
gsl_matrix* pca(const gsl_matrix* data, unsigned int L);
int main() {

    int k = 0, i = 0,j,rows,cols,count = 1,r,c;
    gsl_matrix *red_data,*m;
        rows=5;cols=5;
        m = gsl_matrix_alloc(rows,cols); /* create a matrix */

  /* initialise a matrix */
  for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
      for (j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
      gsl_matrix_set(m,i,j,count);
          count++;
    }

    }


  printf("Matrix m\n");
  for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
      for (j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
      printf("%f ",gsl_matrix_get(m,i,j));
    }
      printf("\n");
    }



    red_data = pca(m,4);
        r = red_data->size1;
        c = red_data->size2;
        printf("rows = %d, columns = %d \n",r,c); 
    for (i = 0; i<r; i++)
         {
             for(k = 0; k < c; k++)
              {
                 printf("%lf  ",gsl_matrix_get(red_data,i,k));
               }
                 printf("\n");  
          } 
    return 0;
}


gsl_matrix* pca(const gsl_matrix* data, unsigned int L)
{
    /*
    @param data - matrix of data vectors, MxN matrix, each column is a data vector, M - dimension, N - data vector count
    @param L - dimension reduction
    */
    assert(data != NULL);
    assert(L > 0 && L < data->size2);
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int rows = data->size1;
    unsigned int cols = data->size2;
    gsl_vector* mean = gsl_vector_alloc(rows);

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        gsl_vector_set(mean, i, gsl_stats_mean(data->data + i * cols, 1, cols));
    }

    // Get mean-substracted data into matrix mean_substracted_data.
    gsl_matrix* mean_substracted_data = gsl_matrix_alloc(rows, cols);
    gsl_matrix_memcpy(mean_substracted_data, data);
    for(i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        gsl_vector_view mean_substracted_point_view = gsl_matrix_column(mean_substracted_data, i);
        gsl_vector_sub(&mean_substracted_point_view.vector, mean);
    }
    gsl_vector_free(mean);

    // Compute Covariance matrix
    gsl_matrix* covariance_matrix = gsl_matrix_alloc(rows, rows);
    gsl_blas_dgemm(CblasNoTrans, CblasTrans, 1.0 / (double)(cols - 1), mean_substracted_data, mean_substracted_data, 0.0, covariance_matrix);
    gsl_matrix_free(mean_substracted_data);

    // Get eigenvectors, sort by eigenvalue.
    gsl_vector* eigenvalues = gsl_vector_alloc(rows);
    gsl_matrix* eigenvectors = gsl_matrix_alloc(rows, rows);
    gsl_eigen_symmv_workspace* workspace = gsl_eigen_symmv_alloc(rows);
    gsl_eigen_symmv(covariance_matrix, eigenvalues, eigenvectors, workspace);
    gsl_eigen_symmv_free(workspace);
    gsl_matrix_free(covariance_matrix);

    // Sort the eigenvectors
    gsl_eigen_symmv_sort(eigenvalues, eigenvectors, GSL_EIGEN_SORT_ABS_DESC);
    gsl_vector_free(eigenvalues);

    // Project the original dataset
    gsl_matrix* result = gsl_matrix_alloc(L, cols);
    gsl_matrix_view L_eigenvectors = gsl_matrix_submatrix(eigenvectors, 0, 0, rows, L);
    gsl_blas_dgemm(CblasTrans, CblasNoTrans, 1.0, &L_eigenvectors.matrix, data, 0.0, result);
    gsl_matrix_free(eigenvectors);

    // Result is n LxN matrix, each column is the original data vector with reduced dimension from M to L
    return result;
}
```

I used below commands:

```
$ gcc pca.c -o pca -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
$ ./pca
```

I have given 5 X 5 matrix and no:of principal components = 4.
I have compared the results to matlab ones. They are not matching. What should I do to get comparable results ?. Or is there any PCA code implemented in C (need not be gsl Library) matching matlab results. Thank you ahead.

Comment: @rayryeng: This is not a dup, OP has code and is asking for debugging help, not a ready-made implementation the dup does!

Comment: @Olaf The OP can compare notes with the dup and see why it isn't working.  However, if you can figure out what the error is, I can reopen and you can answer.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono: This is asking for debugging help, not searching for external code.

Comment: @rayryeng: Did you even read the dup? It is not the same as this question. It should be deleted, but can't be due to your dup-hammer!

Comment: @Olaf OK. Well if you can figure out the bug and if it works, I can reopen and you can answer.  Otherwise, I'm going to leave it closed.

Comment: @rayryeng: I can't answer this one, as it lacks information. I'd CV as missing that. My point is deleting the dup, as that is definitively OT.

Comment: hey I want results which are comparable to Matlab. If you guys can help me it would be great. I would appreciate even if there is another implementation in C.

Comment: @JyothiKumar: See [ask] and follow the advice. Your question lacks information.

Comment: Above code is not giving results comparable to matlab. I need a code which does this @Olaf

Comment: @JyothiKumar: Please read the linked page **carefully**. Without more details it is not clear if you are looking for external resources or after debugging help. The first is off-topic here, the second need more details (e.g. what your debugger says). Without that the question is likely to be close for one or the other reason (or as unclear for the undecided).

Comment: @JyothiKumar If you have an expected output or format, you need to include that in your question. Then include your output of what your code is giving you currently.